# MVC 5 C# web application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

Can somebody clarify those things:

1. I have created my tables in a sql server.
2. Created project in VS, and changed the connectionstring in web.config to point out to my db. It works for adding a user, and I can see the user info in my User table. But it does not work for creating an item forexample a Book item. The result is I got new table inserted in my db called Books, but I already have a table for Book, it should be stored in Book not in Books?
3. So please what I am missing or doing wrong?

I have also added a context file called `DefaultConnection.cs` with the following content:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace Example.Models
    {
        public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
        {
            // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
            // enter code here**`strong text`**
            // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
            // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
            // For more information refer to the documentation:
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

            public DefaultConnection()
                : base("name=DefaultConnection")
            {
            }

            public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Exaple.Models.Book> Books { get; set; }


        }
    }
```

`

Comment: You need to define your `Books` in `ApplicationDbContext`. you don't need to create another context

Comment: But when I add a scafollded item, it asks for a context, can I leave it empty?

Comment: So the context is `ApplicationDbContext` in a default MVC 5.0 app

Comment: IMHO, I'd suggest you start with [getting to know EF](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which is a broad topic (conventions, annotations, etc.) which cover a part of your question. You will really need to regardless because it's quite broad and you'll need it if you go the "EF way" - it's not "required" nor "the only way", but if you _want_ to use it, you have to really grasp it. Hth...

Answer (score 0):

another option if you want yo use another DbContext, is add the attribute Table to the class Book:

```
[Table("Book")]
public class Book {....}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, You need to define your `Books` in `ApplicationDbContext`. you don't need to create another context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
}
```

Comment: Then I got the following error: The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269). Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             return View(db.Books.ToList());
Line 21:         }
Line 22:

Comment: You have to [enable migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx) and change your database schema

Comment: First `Enable-Migrations` then `Update-Database` command in the PowerShell Manager Console

Comment: Could you please tell how to do that?

Comment: Thanks Sirwan it helped fix the first problem, but I still get Books table in my db instead of updating the existing Book table with the entry.